# My LaTeX strings look bold when zooming out in the printed figure

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, mathjax, export-to-pdf

I'm using Plotly to generate my figures for a research article. I need to export my figure in EPS or PDF and I have an issue that doesn't appear if I export in PNG.

LaTeX strings got bold when exporting the figure.
I don't know how to resolve the problem. Do you know any command to remove this bold effect?

[image: Screenshot of the figure with bold labels (which shouldn't be) written in latex]

Here is the python code to write the labels for example

```
fig.update_yaxes(row=1, col=1, title=r"$\boldsymbol{\tau} \; \text{(N)}$")
for i in range(2, rows + 1):
    fig.update_yaxes(row=i, col=1, title=r"$\boldsymbol{\tau} \; \text{(Nm)}$")
for i in range(1, cols + 1):
    fig.update_xaxes(row=rows, col=i, title=r"$\text{Time (s)}$")
```

This is how I export the figure:

```
fig.write_image(out_path_file + "/q_integrated.png")
fig.write_image(out_path_file + "/q_integrated.pdf")
fig.write_html(out_path_file + "/q_integrated.html", include_mathjax="cdn")
fig.write_image(out_path_file + "/q_integrated.eps")
```

Comment: A [mcve] would probably help.